# Default mode with USB, charging + USB Tethering?

Tags: cyanogenmod, usb-tethering

Is there anyway to make it so that my phone, when connected with a USB Data Cable to a computer automatically turns on USB Tethering?

Currently using Cyanogenmod 13.

I tried changing the option in Developer Options to `RNDIS` however it doesn't seem to work (by that I mean it doesn't seem to do what USB Tethering does), and it doesn't hold when I unplug and plug back in.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Yes, that's quite easy to do but  would more or less require root access. Use Tasker with Secure Settings or just Automate (llama) or provide us the information of your Android version and device.

Comment: I'm using CM13, rooted.

Comment: Android 6+ permissions changes made this impossible, this settings in Developer options is a hold over from older versions of the Android source code which likely just hasn't been removed yet, as far as we can tell it has no real world function, other than to allow some modes that may not appear in the regular USB menu if the device is equipped/capable. Regardless of the setting, the connection will return to Charge Only mode on the next connection.

Comment: Dang. Not possible isn't what I expected from an Android. It's a pain in the ass to click through 3 menus to turn on USB tethering. I just want to plug it into my router and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to make it so that my phone, when connected with a USB Data Cable to a computer automatically turns on USB Tethering?

Yes. Use [automation](/questions/tagged/automation). I successfully tested my solution using [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) v1.1.13 on CM13 (build:ZNH0EAO1QE).

You would need to make a flow and it should fairly look like this:

<sub>(Click an image to enlarge it)</sub>

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Alternatively, you can use Tasker to detect the USB connection and then run this command with root access:

```
service call connectivity 30 i32 1
```